# Why does $N$ need to be normal? (Robinson exercise)

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

In Robinson Ed. 2, Ex. 1.3.16 he asks: if $H\le K\le G$ and $N\lhd G$ and $KN=HN$ and $K\cap N =H\cap N$ then show $H=K$.  My question is: does $N$ need to be normal in $G$?

Here's my attempted proof:  It's enough to show $K\le H$. Let $k\in K$.  Then there's an $h\in H$ such that $kN = hN$.  So $h^{-1}k\in N$ but it's also in $K$, and therefore $h^{-1}k\in K\cap N = H\cap N$ and so $h^{-1}k\in H$ therefore $k\in H$.

I'm sure I went wrong somewhere.  Where did I use normality?

[I'm returning to maths and group theory after *many* years, and I do remember always struggling with the intuitive meaning of normality in the past, even though the definition is simple.]

Comment: You didn't. (BTW I think your first statement is false, and what you should have is $hm=kn$ for some $h\in H$ and $m,n\in N$. And then all is OK).

Comment: Thanks @ancientmathematician.  You mean $kN=hN$ is false?  Surely there must be two equal cosets?

Comment: @ancientmathematician I don't think OP's first statement is false. Given $k\in K$, $k=hn$ for some $h\in H, n\in N$ and then we see that $kN=hnN=hN$

Comment: @IgnorantMathematician you are right, what I should have said was that it wasn't immediately obvious.

Comment: Ok, I can accept that.  I could have said, since $KN=HN$ are unions of disjoint cosets of N (perhaps with repetitions), the coset $kN\subset KN$ is equal to one of the cosets $hN\subset HN$.  It feels better, somehow, to argue about cosets than about individual group elements.  And to me it was "immediately obvious" without having to calculate group elements, I suppose.

Comment: Which of Robinson's books are you referring to? Because neither his *"A Course in the Theory of Groups (Second Edition)"* nor his *"Abstract Algebra (Second Edition)"* correspond to this exercise.

Comment: @Shaun you're right, it should say Ex. 1.3.16.  This is "A course in the theory of groups" second edition.  I'll edit it.

Comment: I don't have a copy of Robinson, but at least in some places the product $HK=\{hk\mid h\in H, k\in K\}$ of two subgroups $H,K\le G$ is never used unless at least one of the subgroups is normal. Simply because $HK$ won't necessarily be a subgroup otherwise.

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen I think you might have got to the bottom of it.  KN doesn't need to be a subgroup in this proof (I believe) but maybe Robinson wasn't particularly interested in the case where it's not a subgroup.  He does, however, on page 11, explicitly define the notation XY for arbitrary non-empty SUBSETS X and Y of a group.

Comment: @AndrewKay That may be all there is to it. And your argument is fine.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the statement that theres an $h$ in $H$ such that $hN=kN$ need not hold, and we can see this in the following counterexample when $N$ is not normal. Consider $G=A_4$ the alternating group on $4$ elements, $N=\langle e,(132),(123)\rangle$, $H=\langle e,(12)(34)\rangle$, $K=\langle e,(12)(34),(13)(24),(14)(23)\rangle$. We have that $NH=NK=A_4$, since the size of this subgroup is at least $6$ and $A_4$ has no index $2$ subgroups. We also have $H\cap N=K\cap N=e$, since the orders are coprime.

In this example, if we picked $k$ to be $(13)(24)\in K$, then there would be no element $h$ in $H$ such that $h^{-1}k\in N$, since this would have to be the identity (because $N\cap K=e$), and $k\notin H$.

Comment: $NH$ has order 6, not 12, so we cannot possibly have $NH = A_4$. The fact that $A_4$ has no subgroup of order 6 is not relevant, because $NH$ is not a subgroup.

Comment: Oh my mistake, I was interpreting $NH$ to be the subgroup generated by $N$ and $H$ in the case when $N$ is not necessarily normal.